# React refs not being evaluated

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple component in React, witch renders another component as follows.

```
   _getResultsListComponent: function () {
      var data = {
        ...blabla
      };
      return 
          <Popout
            id='popout'
            ref="searchResults"
            closeResults={this._closeResults}
            pointerAlign="center"
         >
            <this.props.resultsList data={data} />
         </Popout>
   },


           render: function () {
                    return (
         <div className='blabla'>
            {this._getResultsListComponent()}
         </div>
      );
   }
```

However, if i print 'this.refs' after mount ill get the exact string ive put into refs, for example:

```
 ref="searchResults"
```

printing this.refs after mount gets me

```
searchResults
```

If i change the refs to

```
 ref="{(compo) => {this.component = compo}}"
```

ill get when printing:

```
{(compo) => {this.component = compo}}
```

Like if the refs are not being evaluated.

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React no longer sets a "refs" object on the class but instead uses a callback so that you can assign a class property a unique name for the element. In this case `this.component` will contain the value of the `compo` prop passed to the callback.

`ref` accepts a `callback` function and you need to remove the quotes for it to be evaluated

```
ref={(compo) => {this.component = compo}}
```

You can later access the ref like `this.component`